Why can't add two variables of enumeration type in c#
It is definitely said that you can add two variables of enumeration type in the c# specification. The following is a definition of enumeration type:
enum MyEnumeration
    {
        E1,
        E2 = 10,
        E3
    }

MyEnumeration myEnum = MyEnumeration.E1;

the following code can't be complied:
myEnum = myEnum + myEnum;

but the following code can be complied:
myEnum++;
myEnum = myEnum + 20;


FWIW myEnum = myEnum | myEnum works.

You cited the language spec. It is important when you read the statements it makes that you also read the links it provides. Those links state:

Enumeration addition. Every enumeration type implicitly provides the
following predefined operators, where E is the enum type, and U is the
underlying type of E:

So that explains why myEnum = myEnum + 20; works.
They also state:

Predefined ++ and -- operators exist for the following types: sbyte, byte, short, ushort, int, uint, long, ulong, char, float, double, decimal, and any enum type.

So that explains why myEnum++; works.
The docs never state that myEnum = myEnum + myEnum; should work. So it doesn't.
Now at a practical level - it likely doesn't support this since it is a somewhat nonsensical thing to do. Granted, you could make a similar argument for ++. But for 95% of cases, when you think you want var myEnum = myEnum1 + myEnum2; you really want var myEnum = myEnum1 | myEnum2;.

As a fun aside, you can use Enum.Value + Enum.Value inside another enum: https://rextester.com/RSBZP92077

@ProgrammingLlama Clever. Well spotted.

Enum variables cannot be directly used with the addition operator. It is not defined for enum types. The addition operator works with integer variables due to specific language rules and implicit casting. For you to make below code work:
myEnum = myEnum + myEnum;

You need to add an Explicit casting like below:
myEnum = (int)myEnum + myEnum;

Refer to the below code for reference:
using System;
            
enum MyEnumeration
{
   E1,
   E2 = 10,
   E3       
}

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        MyEnumeration myEnum = MyEnumeration.E1;
        MyEnumeration myEnum2 = MyEnumeration.E2;
        
        myEnum = (MyEnumeration)((int)myEnum + (int)myEnum);
        Console.WriteLine("Value at first : "+myEnum); // Value at first : E1
        
        myEnum++;
        myEnum++;       
        var result = myEnum + 20;
        Console.WriteLine("Value at second : " +result); // Value at second : 22
        
        var result2 = (MyEnumeration)((int)myEnum2 + (int)myEnum2);
        Console.WriteLine("Value at third : "+result2); //Value at third : 20
    }
}


Refer the working .netfiddle here

